# How to make a list of files that don't exist from a list of files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a text file `a.txt` that contains a list of files:

```
photo/a.jpg
photo/b.jpg
photo/c.jpg
etc
```

I want to get a list of the files that don't exist.

Comment: A oneliner `xargs -n1 -I{} bash -c "[[ ! -e {} ]] && echo {}" < a.txt > b.txt`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
xargs -I % bash -c '[[ ! -e $1 ]] && echo "$1"' _ % < a.txt > b.txt
```

`xargs` will run `bash -c` for each line in `a.txt`. `[[ ! -e $1 ]]` will check for non-presence of each entry.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. And then to put it into a file (because I'm checking 40k files and the output will be long), I just need to append `> b.txt` on that command, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct, `cat a.txt | xargs -I % bash -c '[[ ! -e $1 ]] && echo "$1"' _ % > b.txt`

Comment: What is the meaning of the `_` ?

Comment: That is for passing arguments to `bash -c` and `_` for passing just `_` in `$0`. It can be `cat a.txt | xargs -I % bash -c '[[ ! -e $1 ]] && echo "$1"' '' %` as well.

Comment: Ah got it! I found `cat a.txt | xargs -I % bash -c '[[ ! -e $0 ]] && echo "$0"' %` working too.. But thanks for pointing me towards the fact that `$0` is not set when using `bash -c`!

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to involve `cat`, or to invoke a separate shell for each line in the file; a simple `while read` loop will suffice here:

```
while read -r file
do
    [ -e "$file" ] || echo "$file"
done < a.txt
```

Read each line one by one. Test for the existence of each file and print its name if it doesn't exist.

Just as the input is passed to the loop using `<`, the output of the loop can be written to a file using `> out.txt`.